# How can I dynamically choose smart or non-smart quotes?

Tags: text

In Keynote and Pages (and other apps), I can set a preference in the Auto-correction pane to use smart quotes.  However, I'm writing a bunch of slides that include code.  When typing the code, I don't want to use smart quotes, as they are syntactically incorrect for the language I'm using.  On the other hand, I often have descriptive text where I'd like to use the smart quotes.

I'm getting sick of bringing up the preferences pane several times in a row, just to switch my smart quotes preference back and forth.  There has to be an easier way. I know that cmd-, makes getting to the preference pane easy, but then I have to click one or more mouse clicks.

Is there?  Can I do something so that my smart quote choice is made as I type the quote?
Or is there a way to make the switching easier?
Or can I map a different key somewhere to "smart quote"?  That wouldn't be so bad -- hit the caps lock key for smart quote and the regular key for straight quotes.  Oh, wait, I need to do that for apostrophe also. . .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

iWork '09 apps don't seem to have an Edit > Substitutions menu, but in ones that do you can set up a custom shortcut for toggling the Smart Quotes item:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I came up with an entirely different suggestion.
Turn off the automatic smart quotes altogether, and learn to type them manually instead.

On the U.S. standard keyboard layout:

Open printer's quote `“` can be typed manually by `Option-[`.

Close printer's quote `”` can be typed manually by `Shift-Option-[`.

Open printer's apostrophe `‘` can be typed manually by `Option-]`.

Close printer's apostrophe `’` can be typed manually by `Shift-Option-]`.

So if you can train yourself to touch-type those key combinations, you can go back and forth from straight quotes to printer's quotes without needing to toggle system settings.

Comment: Or you can customize these for a more sensible combination: http://www.danandcheryl.com/2010/08/how-to-type-curly-quotes-in-mac-os-x

Comment: I do something similar. I dynamically choose between straight quotes and curly quotes, without even thinking about it. When I want straight quotes, I type `"`. When I want curly quotes, I type `Option` `"` or `Option` `Shift` `"`. I have a french keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use system prefs/language & text/text/symbol and text substitution to set up shortcuts for this.

Smart stuff already has keyboard shortcuts:  Option and Option + Shift plus [, Option and Option + Shift plus ] on a US layout.  “ ” ‘ ’  These could be remapped with Ukelele.