# How can I stop Messages app from using so-called "smart" quotes?

Tags: messages, text, macos

I have "smart" quotes turned off in my System Preferences, because I *hate* having a computer that thinks it is smarter than me, and it breaks so many things.  But for some reason the Messages app has decided to ignore my explicitly stated preferences, and automatically change normal quotation marks to so-called "smart" quotes.

I also looked in the Preferences of the Messages app, and there is nothing there that mentions "smart" quotes.  So neither system-wide nor app-specific preferences are the issue.

None of the current questions that appeared in a search answer my question:

- I'm not using [TextEdit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/373113/3553)
- or [BBEdit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/434646/second-double-quotation-changing-to-smart-quotes)
- I'm not asking [how to do this dynamically](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40215/how-can-i-dynamically-choose-smart-or-non-smart-quotes)

How can I make Messages stop spitting in my face and use exactly what I typed and not what its programmers think I should have typed?

Comment: I have reproduced this and filed FB11789961 with Apple to report it as a bug

Comment: @Ezekiel I have a similar issue except messages uses the French-style “guillemots” after I had the system language set to French and set it back to English. Is that worth reporting separately or do you think Apple would find and fix that with your bug report?

Comment: @RusticChevalier: I would report it separately but include a link to the other report as possibly related.

Comment: @Ezekiel: yes, I think it is _definitely_ a bug.  Thanks for reporting it!

Comment: Many apps, including Messages, have their own individual settings for smart quotes - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xnew6.png - not governed by the global pref. [In such as TextEdit, it's actually saved at document-level.] It's not clear from your question whether you've tested this.

Comment: @Tetsujin I looked in the Preferences of Messages, but it didn't occur to me that they would hide their preferences as check-marked menu items ‍♂️.  If you put that in an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many Apple apps, including Messages, have their own individual settings for smart quotes in Edit > Substitutions

[image]

These are not governed by the global pref.
[In such as TextEdit, it's actually saved at document-level.]

Comment: Did you test if that works? That's off for me but it still does smart quotes

Comment: @Ezekiel - Works absolutely fine for me. I disable them everywhere, so i've had to chase them round the occasional errant app before - which is also how I discovered TextEdit keeps that at document level. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGmKR.png

Comment: Hmm - definitely not working here. I've got them off in System Settings and off in this menu and it's still changing them: "This is a “test” with them off". The inner quotes around test were typed in Messages. The outer quotes in Safari.

Comment: Just double-checked, Mojave & Monterey, same in both.

Comment: @Ezekiel: please try the extra info I added, which I think explains why it's not working for you:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/450648

Comment: @iconoclast great, that worked.

Answer (score 3):

As an addendum to the very useful answer from Tetsujin,

In Messages, there are actually 2 places "smart" quotes are set, so besides unchecking Edit → Substitutions → Smart Quotes, you also need to open the dialog box at Edit → Substitutions → Show Substitutions and uncheck

[image: menu item where you need to uncheck "smart" quotes]

[image: dialog box where you need to uncheck "smart" quotes]

Unfortunately this is an extremely buggy part of the app, and Messages might re-check the "smart" quotes checkbox after you uncheck it.  The procedure that finally worked for me was to

1. uncheck everything in that dialog box
2. restart Messages
3. check Text Substitution (which I want, to replace `")` with  , for example)
4. restart Messages
5. verify that "Smart" quotes is NOT checked

In the procedure above, Messages did check "smart" dashes against my will, but I guess I can live with that.

Comment: The prefs sheet should simply be a mirror of what is set in the menus - change one, the other changes at the same time. It just gives you a couple more options is all.

Comment: @Tetsujin That's _definitely not_  the behavior I'm seeing in macOS 12.6 (21G115).  What version of macOS are you using? You can see above in my screenshots that the settings were different.  And Ezekiel's experience seems to have matched mine.

Comment: I do see a bug in 12.6, but it's in activating that prefs window. It's greyed out & can't be interacted with until you click its title bar, then it springs into action & also correctly reflects any changes you make in the menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

When used system-wide, "smart" quotes break code, but I'm rarely if ever sending code snippets via Messages.  The main thing broken in Messages are OS-wide automatic text replacements from System Preferences → Keyboard → Text.  For example, `")` is set up to be replaced with this emoji: .

Unless there's a way of *stopping* this errant behavior, my (hopefully temporary) workaround is to reverse it.  So, for every text replacement that uses quotation marks—whether single or double—I've had to create a duplicate version with "smart" quotes.

Messages didn't use these until I restarted it.

If someone comes up with a better solution I will definitely choose theirs over my workaround.